# How to pass fit parameters from one sklearn pipeline step to another?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

```py
p = Pipeline([
  ('pre', Preprocessing()),
  ('clf', KerasClassifier()),
])
```

After fitting `Preprocessing` it will contain trained `tokenizer` and I want to use that tokenizer inside `clf.fit`. Is there any way to pass it?

---

Checked [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/pipeline.py#L307) and it looks like there is no way. Sadly I need to fit tokenizer manually beforehand and pass it to each pipeline steps.

Or by using ugly hack: make `preprocessing.transform` return tuple with transformed data and tokenizer instead of just data, and then inside `clf.fit` unpack that tuple.

---

End up with ugly hack:

```py
class Preprocessing(TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator):
    ...

    def transform(self, X):
        ...
        return X, self.tokenizer.word_index


class CustomClassifier(KerasClassifier):
    def fit(self, X, y, sample_weight=None, **kwargs):
        X, word_index = X
        self.sk_params['word_index'] = word_index
        return super(NNClassifier, self).fit(X, y, sample_weight, **kwargs)

    def predict(self, X, **kwargs):
        X, _ = X
        return super().predict(X, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Could you assign `Preprocessing` instance to a variable and pass by reference into `KerasClassifier`? `pre = Preprocessing(); p = Pipeline([
  ('pre', pre),
  ('clf', KerasClassifier(tokenizer=pre.tokenizer)),
])`